# Can't figure out how to rename file in remote directory on 4690 using Python

Tags: python, logging, rename

I am trying to leverage the RotatingFileHandler for logging. For whatever reason the base call in the handler to rename the files after it hits the max size, is os.rename (Source -> dest) which essentially moves the current file to *log.1 and create a new file .log.

My dilemma is this, this function works without any issue on my local (mac) but does not work on the 4690. No matter I define the filename full path, just the filename it either can't rename the file because the file name is too long or it doesn't find it.

Below is a sample code extracted out just to get the os.rename working

File test.py

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import platform
import sys

BOX_TYPE             = os.uname()[4]
POS_TYPE             = 'i686'
LINUX_TYPE           = 'arm64'


## think I need to change this up to only set the dir not the filenames
if  BOX_TYPE == 'i686' or BOX_TYPE == 'x86_64':
    ## log location on 4690
    LOGFILE = 'F:/logs/hwinfo/HWINFO.LOG'
elif BOX_TYPE == LINUX_TYPE:
    ## log location on my local
    LOGFILE = '/Users/t2stric/Repositories/tredata-tools/hwInfo/5594US/hwInfo.log'


print ( "LOGFILE: " + LOGFILE)
os.getcwd()
os.rename (LOGFILE, LOGFILE + ".1")
```

When I run on my local it changes the filename in the designated directory from hwInfo.log -> hwInfo.log.1

On 4690, here you can see the file is present.

```
t2stric@@CC5579.US C:QATOOLS/>dir F:/logs/hwinfo/HWINFO.LOG

  Volume in drive vf: has no label
  Directory of vf:logs/hwinfo/

   9-08-2023  10:34a     86289  HWINFO.LOG
```

But when I run it there I get the following error

```
t2stric@@CC5579.US C:QATOOLS/>python3 test.py
LOGFILE: F:/logs/hwinfo/HWINFO.LOG
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 46, in <module>
    os.rename (LOGFILE, LOGFILE + ".1")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'F:/logs/hwinfo/HWINFO.L
OG' -> 'F:/logs/hwinfo/HWINFO.LOG.1'
```

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated. I know this might be a little different because 4690 is like a blend of DOS and Linux so it doesn't exactly fit most normal circumstances.

I have tried using just the file name hoping it could just rename the file in the same directory.
This works fine from my local (mac) using the rotatingFileHandler or the TimedRotatingFileHandler.

But it doesn't work on 4690. I either get the filename is too long or I get the file is not found even though it is present.

Normal logging occurs without a problem, the issue comes when it is time to rotate the logs, the system isn't able to rename the files.

Comment: I'm mostly amazed that Python works on the 4690 operating system at all. I can't find any examples of people on StackOverflow using this combination. You might be the first.

Comment: I know little about Windows, and even less about DOS, but maybe the issue is the file path separator. DOS uses \ as a path separator, which you'll have to type as \\ in Python, because backslash is also the escape character in Python. Maybe the command line is not picky about slashes vs backslashes, but Python requires backslashes?